# Java Rest Web service and Angular Table with data lazy load

Tags: java, angularjs, oracle, rest, lazy-loading

I want to create table using AngularJS. I'm getting table data from server(I use rest web service)

I want to make table as lazy loaded. Do you have any idea how to reach that ?

I mean if i have big data(too many row is database) and if i will return whole table in json format, front side seems to be frozen.

I need load first  100 row, create table with paginator, if user clicks next page on paginator angular calls web service again and shows next 100 rows in next page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does lazy loaded table mean? When should it be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it done quick an painless, can I recommend to you [DataTable](https://datatables.net/)? It takes the data and automatically makes a table out of it, with pages and limits that you can easily define. You can check the [installation manual here](https://datatables.net/manual/installation), it is VERY easy to set-up and get going, and does what you need done for you automatically.

Comment: And how to implement server side ?

Comment: @zuri Either return your data as an html table or as a json object through Ajax. If you can be more specific I can help you, no problem. I'm currently using it on a project of mine and I don't mind showing you some code.